# In python, what code should I generate to do "from FILE import *"?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm working on the [pythonizer](https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer), a program to translate perl to python, and I'm looking to translate the statement "require FILENAME;" to python.  In this case I need to generate "from FILENAME import *".  I figured out the "from FILENAME" part (here `BASENAME` is the `FILENAME` without the path or extension):

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
module = SourceFileLoader(BASENAME, FILENAME).load_module()
```

and the `import *` part is coded as:

```
__import__(name, fromlist=['*'])
```

but how do I combine them?

I see [_handle_fromlist](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1053) in `importlib._bootstrap`, but calling an internal routine is most likely not the right answer here.

Comment: As an aside, you should hopefully realise that `from something import *` is usually a *spectacularly* bad idea :-)

Comment: Of course I know that - I'm just trying to translate the semantics of the perl code.

Comment: No probs, snoopyjc, just making sure it's brought to everyone's attention :-)

Comment: You're generating code. The code to generate for `from FILE import *` is `from FILE import *`. Why would it be anything else?

Comment: (`require` means something very different from `import *`, and this translation you're performing is going to lead to bugs.)

Comment: `from` doesn't take a filename - it wants a module name as the `FILE`.

Comment: Yes this is only part of the translation

Answer (score 1):

Here is my second thought about implementing this:

```
[_p, _m] = _prep_import(FILENAME)
sys.path.insert(0, _p)
__import__(_m, fromlist=['*'])
sys.path.pop(0)

def _prep_import(filepath):
    """Prepare a filepath for import by getting the abspath, splitting
    it from the filename, and removing any extension.  Returns a tuple of
    the path and the filename"""
    return os.path.split(os.path.splitext(os.path.abspath(filepath))[0])
```

Where `_prep_import()` looks at the FILENAME (which may be an expression), removes any extension, grabs any path info from it into the first result, and leaves the basename as the second result.  Note that the FILENAME may contain dashes (`-`), and I believe `__import__` is OK with that.